# How to switch to light mode despite dark mode setting for the phone

Tags: c#, xamarin, maui

In my application I have defined colors for my controls. Mostly like this

```xml
{StaticResource Black}
```

some like this because I had some problems with changing the color when I set the value to disabled

```xml
{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray200}, Dark={StaticResource Gray200}}
```

Addition, when starting the application, I set the mode to Light in this way:

```cs
Current.UserAppTheme = AppTheme.Light;
```

But even so, if the phone has any settings for dark mode, my dialogues triggered in this way

```cs
Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert
```

have a gray background instead of white. And there are some cases where, for example, the Editor has a black background instead of a white one.

How do I force my phone to go into light mode when using my app?

Comment: You always want it to be light or do you want an option that triggers this?

Comment: You need to fight both Android and IOS. For Android you need to modify styles. Not sure for IOS, but there should be an option in info.plist somewhere.

Comment: @FreakyAli I create only one interface for light mode. I would like to my user always light.  But current with set Current.UserAppTheme = AppTheme.Light; it don't work correctly if user have set dark mode for phone.

Comment: @H.A.H. I defined the style for my controls by defining one color or if I distinguished between dark and light mode it gave the same color anyway. But, for example, I don't have an option to set the colors for "DisplayAlert", they depend on the phone's mode, and I would like them to always be in light mode without having to create custom dialog.

Comment: @SilnyToJa to be honest, if DisplayAlert is all your problem, just use custom popup and get this over with.

Comment: @H.A.H. displayAlert has the most noticeable change when switching to dark mode, but most of the interface is also dimmed, and for one device the backgroud for editor also changed to black instead of white. So the problem is not only with display alert.

Comment: Do you call this, editor: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/editor?view=net-maui-7.0?

Comment: You can change the value of controls in Styles.xml: `Dark={StaticResource XXX}`. But it's verbose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To prevent Dark mode in Maui you need to force it by applying it natively.

In my opinion, this is the better solution than applying hacks in cross-platform code, Even though not handling dark mode is a hack in itself.

In your native android activity in the onCreate method add the following:

```
AppCompatDelegate.DefaultNightMode = AppCompatDelegate.ModeNightNo;
```

Whereas for iOS you need to edit the `Info.plist` file and add the following:

```
<key>UIUserInterfaceStyle</key>
<string>Light</string>
```

Some devices might need you to add the following to your App's constructor:

```
public App()
{
   Application.Current.UserAppTheme = AppTheme.Light;
}
```

This is probably because MAUI is messing around with your themes in the background not sure how and why

Answer (score 2):

If you want your app to be in light mode even if device is in dark mode, you have to override the default theme in the app.

For each view (codeBehind) add this line inside the constructor:

```
Application.Current.UserAppTheme = AppTheme.Light;
```

Then, Go to Platforms find for Android folder and add `AppCompatDelegate.DefaultNightMode = AppCompatDelegate.ModeNightNo;`
to the MainApplication class constructor.

**These two steps are mandatory to get the required result.**

Comment: Add this directly to your App, that would be better

Comment: @FreakyAli I tried that before but some time it didn't worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by Josh Brunton, you can just set it globally in the App class. (I would upvote it but I do not yet have enough rep) Microsoft's own documentation recommends it, as seen here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/system-theme-changes?view=net-maui-8.0#set-the-current-user-theme

`Application.Current.UserAppTheme = AppTheme.Dark;`

Comment: Now you probably can :)

Answer (score 0):

To force light mode in your app, just set the `UserAppTheme` to `AppTheme.Light` in the App's constructor:

.../App.xaml.cs

```
namespace MyProject 
{
    public partial class App 
    {
        UserAppTheme = AppTheme.Light;

        // or, fully qualified: 
        Application.UserAppTheme = Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModel.AppTheme.Light;
    }
}
```